# Some questions about "-set-xmark" in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I have a rule as following:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 10.228.20.15/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80--tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j MARK --set-xmark 0x70/0xffffffff
```

The man doc explains `--set-xmark` as below:

**Zero out the bits given by mask and XOR value into the ctmark.**

English is not my native language. Could anyone help to explain what value would be set into ctmark?
What zero out means? Take a example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

So the syntax is `--set-xmark value/mask`. The resulting operation is:

```
ctmark = (ctmark AND NOT mask) XOR value
```

Zero-out corresponds to `(ctmark AND NOT mask)`: if a bit in `mask` is set, then the corresponding bit in `ctmark` will be zero (before the XOR).

The man page also states:

```
--and-mark bits
    Binary AND the  ctmark  with  bits.  (Mnemonic  for  --set-xmark
    0/invbits, where invbits is the binary negation of bits.)

--or-mark bits
    Binary  OR  the  ctmark  with  bits.  (Mnemonic  for --set-xmark
    bits/bits.)

--xor-mark bits
    Binary XOR the  ctmark  with  bits.  (Mnemonic  for  --set-xmark
    bits/0.)
```

You can validate the operation above against those definitions:

```
--and-mark bits == --set-xmark 0/invbits
     ctmark AND bits = (ctmark AND NOT invbits) XOR 0
     -> bits = NOT invbits
     -> anything XOR 0 = anything
     so: ctmark AND bits = ctmark AND NOT NOT bits = ctmark AND bits

--or-mark bits == --set-mark bits/bits
     ctmark OR bits = (ctmark AND NOT bits) XOR bits
     -> should be obvious based on boolean logic

--xor-mark bits == -set-mark bits/0
     ctmark XOR bits = (ctmark AND NOT 0) XOR bits
     -> anything AND NOT 0 = anything
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's very helpful for me to understand.