# iptables prevents wifi connection

Tags: wifi, iptables

I have a wifi access point with a captive portal set up, but i cant connect to the network unless i allow the mac in forehand

(`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 0:0:0:0:0:0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0`)

What packets do i need to allow to connect to the network? (not currently working on a nexus 5)

This is the iptables rules i use

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0x0
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 0:0:0:0:0:0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 1:1:1:1:1:1 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --sport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --sport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0x0



iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp -m mark --mark 0x1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE




#Save, reload and view the new rules
iptables-save > /home/pi/rules.v4

iptables-restore < /home/pi/rules.v4

iptables -L
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be using the `--set-xmark` option that executes a `XOR` rather than the `--set-mark` or `--or-mark` options that just set the required bits.

Therefore, on some packets you need that additional rule to execute an additional `XOR` that brings the total number of `XOR` operations to an odd amount.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22003527/3903832) is a useful explanation on the various mark options.